# Create UTC/TimeZone Time string for .ics file Using c#

Tags: c#, timezone, datetime-format

I am dynamicly creating a .ics file that will be used to add an event to a calender. As Part of creating this file I need to convert a time date string like this:

```
2/26/2021 3:30:00 PM
```

in to this format that looks like this:

```
TZID=America/New_York:20130802T103400
```

I have tried this:

```
DateTime.Parse(MY-TIME_DATE).Value.ToString()).ToUniversalTime().ToString()
```

That doesn't work - Can anyone help out with the Syantax to do this please?

Comment: @dropoutcoder - that looks perfect, thank you! - not bad for a drop out. (Nice handle by the way)

Comment: Thanks. I am glad it worked for you.